# I fear I'm about to be replaced. Is it okay to ask about a new position in my company?

Tags: developer, job-description, replacement

I'm a part time IT Assistant at my company; Well that's my official title anyway, as I mostly fell in to the role of Web Developer/Web Master. My supervisors recently asked me to post a few job listings on our website, one of which was a full time marketing/web developer. My company is not huge, only about 50 employees in the office, so it wouldn't be necessary to hire an additional developer or "web guy" in my opinion. The position doesn't require any specific programming experience but it does say in the responsibilities/experience section a few alarming things: performing routine site maintenance, and a solid understanding of website development processes.

Is it okay to ask my supervisor about this in fear of being replaced? I am not being overworked at all, so would it also be bad to ask to take on the extra roles that they listed in the job description and remove the job listing entirely? I only work 24 hours a week currently and was actually going to ask to for few more before they had me post this, now I'm not sure they'll accept since they're looking for a full-timer anyway.

Comment: *"I only work 24 hours a week currently and was actually going to ask to for few more..."* Were you going to ask for full-time? Apparently that's what they're looking for.

Comment: It's always OK to ask about moving to another position (after you have "paid your dues" by working in the current position for a reasonable amount of time, usually not less than a year). The worst they are likely to tell you is no.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you ask, you may not be offered the job. But if you don't ask, you *definitely* won't be offered the job. Ask your supervisor, and tell them why you're concerned.

Comment: "you definitely won't be offered the job" <-- speculation.  They could be considering the OP, but also looking at other candidates.

Comment: @codenoir: answer honestly: Have you ever actually heard of someone being told to post a job opening online for a position that they were actually being considered for?  The only time I've ever heard of such a thing was if the employee was a foreign national working on a visa and the company was forced by law to post the position.  In that case the person knew they had the job.

Comment: In this case, the employer might not know that the OP is considering full time work.  That tiny (but important) fact must be *shared* to be of value to either side.

To add - Strange things happen.  I've heard of companies forcing all their employees to re-apply for the jobs they already have.  Managers got demoted, subordinates got promoted!  "Fluff" employees got the boot.

Comment: @NotMe From what I understand, posting jobs as a formality to show you allowed others to apply is quite common in the US.

Comment: @NotMe, **yes**. It is very, very common to have requirements that jobs be advertised, even if a particular person is already lined up for the role.

Comment: Many (US) companies require that jobs be posted, at least internally, if not externally, before someone can be hired. I was brought in as contract-to-hire at my current and previous positions. In both cases, the job was posted, _and_ I had to interview (with my current boss) for the position. We sat down for the interview, chit-chatted for a few minutes, then the boss pulled out the paperwork and said "I _have_ to go through the formality..."

Answer (score 90):

There is nothing to be lost by asking your supervisor.  Be forthright, "I was posting the jobs to the web site, and this one looks a lot like what I am doing.  Is this something that I can apply for or were you considering me for another position in the company?"  Frame it as a positive and stay enthusiastic.

Comment: This also leaves open the possibility that they may be looking to augment their web staff. (Maybe they want to expand the site?) +1 for asking if you can apply.

Comment: I like the first part of this answer, but do you really think it would bring good to be positive and enthusiastic? While being negative would be really counter-productive, I think that if he appears too positive and enthusiastic he will look like a clueless idiot (because even if not sure, there is a non negligible chance he will be fired, and this should bring concern to anyone enjoying his job). I'd expect him to appear concerned while staying positive and showing confidence he can fill this position well.

Comment: Good point @Shautieh in my mind positive and enthusiastic is not clueless idiot (which it can be).  Don't go into your boss looking like someone kicked your puppy and start out with "So I guess you are going to fire me now".  Totally agree with your last sentence..

Answer (score 2):

You are part time, so they may see you as a flight risk and want to be on the safe side. It isn't really about the work volume, rather a question of "bus factor". Were you full time they might have been more comfortable and not look for alternatives.

Comment: That..actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Bus factor and retention are two entirely separate things.

Comment: @Lilienthal: nevertheless, it takes a special kind of separation of concerns to say, "well, we think Henry's a flight risk, but in managing that flight risk we must be *very careful* not to consider the bus factor in his role, because that's an entirely separate thing".

Comment: @SteveJessop That's not what I'm saying at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should, of course, post the positions exactly as you have been asked to do.  Then, if you want to, formally apply for the position yourself.

Remember that you must *apply,* and that the full-time job must, by law(!), be *posted.* (This is done to satisfy "equal opportunity" requirements in the USA.)

Your employer can't read your mind.  They might well *not* assume that you want to work 40 hours a week on salary. If you wish to be considered as a candidate, then you must formally become one. If you have taken care that "they will speak well of you," then you are obviously likely to be a *favored* candidate, but the formal hiring process must be followed "to the letter of the law" by the company, nonetheless.

Comment: Do you have a reference to back up your claim that all job openings are legally required to be posted? I've seen lots of cases where a position opened up or was created and it was given to an existing employee without the job being publicly posted.